# Filling NaN values with other values from that column based on other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

`INPUT df:`

```
Student_ID   Subject     Weekly_Feedback
100101         NaN         Excellent: 5
100101         NaN         very good:4
100101       Physics       Good: 3
100101         NaN         Excellent: 5
100102         NaN         Excellent: 5
100102       Chemistry     Good: 3
100102         NaN         Good: 3
100102         NaN         very Good: 3
100102         NaN         Needs improvement: 2
```

I want to fill the rows in `Subject` column which has `NaN` values by its corresponding Subject by using `Student_ID`.

`Expected OUTPUT df:`

```
Student_ID   Subject     Weekly_Feedback
100101       Physics      Excellent: 5
100101       Physics      very good:4
100101       Physics      Good: 3
100101       Physics      Excellent: 5
100102       Chemistry    Excellent: 5
100102       Chemistry    Good: 3
100102       Chemistry    Good: 3
100102       Chemistry    very Good: 3
100102       Chemistry    Needs improvement: 2
```

Comment: Use groupby and then a lambda function to apply `ffill` and `bfill` per group: `df['Subject'] = df.groupby("Student_ID")['Subject'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: `df['Subject'] = df.groupby('Student_ID')['Subject'].ffill().bfill()`